# Ясиноватая - этимология названия

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Меня всегда несколько озадачивало название города Донецкой области - Ясиноватая.
Суффикс слова наводит на ассоциации с "синеватая", "длинноватая" и т.д. (это называется "неполнота признака"?). Потом, почему в женском роде? Если от деревни, то тоже странно - в украинском языке слова "деревня" нет, есть только "село". И вообще, от какого слова происходит это странное название.
Спасибо

Comment: А  от  ясеня  производить  не  пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Женский род - от слова станция. Сначала была станция Ясеноватая, потом стал город с этим же названием, только вместо Е стало почему-то И.
2. Откуда название. Из истории.

Эта местность в прежние времена была восточными казацкими форпостами, т.е. "вартами". Варта-пост, дозор. Ясеноватая - Ясеноварта (много ясеней) - когда-то называли Ясна Варта. Рядом Скотоватая - Скотоварта. Старожилы говорят, что там был большой скотный двор и казацкая сторожевая вышка.

Comment: Мне нигде в сети не попадалось название той станции через "е", до неё и на одноименный хутор через "и" везде ссылаются. В словарях пишут просто: от "ясеня" (неназванным способом) образован природно-географический топоним (= ойконим). Версия с "вартами" возникла в форуме горожан, но как с окончательной с ней там не согласились, хотя и сочли любопытной (были ещё две, с "татарским" следом). Похоже, этот вопрос по-прежнему ждёт дотошного исследователя.

Comment: Сведения, видимо, должны быть в местном музее, но у нас ведь нет возможности туда обратиться.Но на сайте Ясиноватой есть сведения, что и станция, и город назывались то с Е, то с И. http://yasinovataya.narod.ru/history.htm    Это и понятно,там много пришлых, "хохлов", они снивелировали под русские северные названия, там обычно деревни на -ватая, -ватое,-ватка.А украинцы вернули орфографию к украинской, там же всё с И.

Comment: >А украинцы вернули орфографию к украинской, там же всё с И.

По-украински тоже через букву *"е"*. Но более твёрдо - *"ясен"* ['Ясэн].

Например, ссылка на статью про ясень в Википедии.

https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD

Comment: Вообще вопрос **интересный** от @Fuchoin Kazuki.

+1

Потому что (я так предполагаю), если бы название Ясиноватая было бы от слова "ясень", то оно бы выглядело как **Ясеневатая**, наверное. 

А если от "ясен", то, более похоже, -- Ясеновата. Но через "е".

Answer (score 1):

Там  рядом есть: речки Очеретоватая, Россоховатая, Куплеватая, Грековатая, Камышеватая, Камышеваха, Камышеватка, Ольховатка,
поселок Ясинiвка.

Видимо от дерева ясень.